# Repeating countries in the power bi location filter

Tags: location, powerbi, hierarchical, repeat, geography

I am working on a project for developing dashboard. The dataset I am using has fields area, country, region, sub region. For many records, country, region and sub region has the same value as that of country. When I show this as visualization (hierarchical geography filter:having area,country,region and sub region within each other) on my Power Bi page, the countries are repeating within each other. How can I resolve this? Any help is appreciated. Additionally, my apologies, if any such question is already raised and I have mistakenly overlooked it. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can set Latitude and Longitude value in your dataset for each specific area.